# Parse JSON that could contain a jsonArray or a boolen value

Tags: android, json

I have  json string that looks like this

> { "company_id": [ 1, "test"  ]}

but it could be

{ "company_id": false }

sometime. If it is a jsonArray I am able to parse it easily but getting exception when it returns Boolean value. How to parse it?

Logcat :

> 01-22 06:52:09.512: W/System.err(6532): org.json.JSONException: Value
>   false at company_id of type java.lang.Boolean cannot be converted to
>   JSONArray 01-22 06:52:09.516: W/System.err(6532):     at
>   org.json.JSON.typeMismatch(JSON.java:100) 01-22 06:52:09.516:
>   W/System.err(6532):   at
>   org.json.JSONObject.getJSONArray(JSONObject.java:553)

Comment: get the value as string first, if it equals to "true" or "false", cast it to Boolean, otherwise cast it to JsonArray

Comment: OR if you have access to the service that returns the json, make it to return always JsonArray

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use try blocks to check for success:

```
try {
    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(json);
    try {
        boolean bool = jsonObject.getBoolean("company_id");
        Log.e("TAG", "It's a boolean: " + bool);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        JSONArray array = jsonObject.getJSONArray("company_id");
        Log.e("TAG", "It's an array: " + array);
    }
} catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: as a suggestion, put the most common case on first place - if 1 in 1000 will return boolean it's good to be in the catch section

Answer (score 1):

You can use `try/catch` to try to obtain `JSONArray` and if exception is thrown, then try to get `Bool`.